# I'm getting an error when running rake run:android (Rhomobile) stating rm_f is undefined for AndroidTools::Module

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, rhomobile, linux-mint

I've reinstalled my OS twice and done about 10 hours of debugging. I am at a loss.

I'm running Linux Mint 14 (so basically Ubuntu) and have gotten the same issue running 32 and 64 bit.

I started off with 64-bit, which, after installing the 32-bit libs, got to the exact same error as I'm now getting with 32-bit.

I've run the script on a previously written source (which worked a few months ago) and I've also run it on a dummy source (just running `rhogen store` and then feeding it to the rake command).

If I search for this error, there is literally only one result on Google which is [my post on the rhomobile Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rhomobile/gdyfRdHeK78). Since that has yet to yield anything, I thought I would reask over here and see if anyone had any insight.

For completeness, [this](http://varuagdiary.blogspot.com/2011/05/setting-up-rhodes-on-ubuntu-1004.html) is the guide I used for properly installing Rhodes. (The official documentation is HORRIBLE!)

Here is the stack trace from the failed `rake run:android`:

```
rm -rf /media/radnadz/Methuselah/Programming/Rhodes/store/bin/target/android/store-tmp.apk
** Execute run:android:emulator
rake aborted!
undefined method `rm_f' for AndroidTools:Module
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/platform/android/build/android_tools.rb:211:in `run_emulator'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/platform/android/build/android.rake:1971:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => run:android:emulator
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is annoyingly simple (if you know where to look).

As the stack trace suggests, the issue originates in the line 211 of `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/platform/android/build/android_tools.rb`.

If you change the line from `rm_f $applog_path if !$applog_path.nil?` to `FileUtils.rm_f $applog_path if !$applog_path.nil?` then the issue is resolved.

Thanks to Alexey on the rhomobile Google Group for the solution!